# How can send a UDP broadcast to *any* wildcard IP address on the network?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, ip-address, broadcast

I'm trying to send a UDP broadcast to any machine within my subnet.  It works well when I specify the IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.19), but I need it to be generic (192.168.x.x). How can I do that?

I tried `IPAddress.Any,` but it's not working. I don't even know what the term is called (IP Masking, maybe?).

```
private void StartUdpListener()
{
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
    //IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.xxx.xxx"), listenPort); // How can I have a wildcard here?

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
            byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {groupEP} :");
            Console.WriteLine($" {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)}");
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how UDP works. Either it's unicast (a single IP) or it's broadcast (the whole network). If it's broadcast, it will go as far as the router, in other words the whole LAN range. You *cannot* broadcast to a different network. So if your network address is `192.168.1.0/24`, you can only broadcast to `192.168.1.x`. Whereas if your network address is `192.168.0.0/16` you can broadcast to `192.168.x.x`. You cannot choose who to broadcast to.

Comment: Also `listener` should be in a `using` block